# How to perform form validation in a viewpager and restrict user from swiping to next fragment until all fields are filled?

Tags: android, forms, validation, android-fragments, android-viewpager

I have a viewpager that has 6 fragments each containing different input fields. I want to validate each fragment before user moves to next fragment. the viewpager is in an activity.

Comment: Somthing like `inputField.isEmpty() || anotherInputField.isEmpty(); //and so...`  ?

Comment: Yes. Also, to stop the swipe gesture and make sure the fields are filled before user can swipe to next fragment

Comment: Just put some conditional if statements. Like if an input field is empty, disable swipe. that should be easy to do though

Comment: BTW, you should post some code so people can help you better

Comment: ok. how do i reference the views in the fragment inside the activity that contains the viewpager?

Comment: What have you concretely done? Post your code!!